# Counting the many-to-many value in filter

Tags: python, django, model

I am trying to do like this

my class is here

```
class TweetJson(models.Model):

    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Station)
```

and filter

```
MyText.objects.filter(Q(authors__count__gte=1))
```

However it returns.

```
Related Field got invalid lookup: count
```

is there any way to count the number of many-to-many objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can count the number of related objects by annotating:

```
from django.db.models import Count

MyText.objects.filter(
    nauthors=Count('authors')
).filter(nauthors__gte=1)
```

Here you are however filtering on `MyText`s with at least one author. You can do that by filtering for non-`NULL` values and then return a distinct set:

```
MyText.objects.filter(authors__isnull=False).distinct()
```

Comment: Thank you for answer and alternative way, I have tried `__isnull` though not knowing `distinct()`

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to do this is [shown here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/).

What you need to is that first annotate each `TweetJson` with the count of `authors`:

```
from django.db.models import Count
TweetJson.objects.annotate(num_authors=Count('authors'))
```

And, after this you can perform the `__gte` lookup on annotated field:

```
TweetJson.objects.annotate(num_authors=Count('authors')).filter(num_authors__gte=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can count like this also:

```
from django.db.models import Count


MyText.objects.annotate(no_of_authors=Count('authors')).filter(no_of_authors__gte=1)
```

Hope this will work for you.